# HTTP Request contributes to what limits on force.com platform?

Tags: governorlimits

There's a per-apex-session limits which HTTP Request, like how many request can be issued inside one apex session, in total how much time the http request can spend.

Besides those, what else limits will http request contribute to? like at platform level, or inside 24-hour time cycle, what else limits?

Answer (score 1):

http requests are considered as callouts in Salesforce. Mostly limits on callout is based on transaction as below:
1. 100 callouts in one transaction.
2. Total time given for callout is 120 seconds. That means you can have 2 callouts taking 60seconds each or 100 callouts taking 1.2 second each.
There is no limit on number of callouts that you can make in 24hours window.

Answer (score 1):

[Callout Limits and Limitations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_timeouts.htm) gives you a complete list of limits. There's *one* limit that applies across multiple transactions, and that is you're allowed only 20 concurrent calls across all transactions to non-Salesforce endpoints.